# Why is there an "illegal start of type" error at every else clause?

Tags: java

I am doing the sololearn course on java and every time I use the else command it always gives an error saying that I have an "illegal start of type"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
       int number = read.nextInt();
       
       //your code goes here
        if(number % 10 == 0 || number % 9 == 0);
            System.out.println("You won $200");
        if(number % 4 == 0 || number % 6 == 0);
            System.out.println("You won $50");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Try again");
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using. I am using "else" the same way they use it in the examples. The practice is the logical statements practice in lesson 14.

Comment: please remove ";" from end of the sentence of if condition. pls check syntax https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp

Comment: I fixed the problem with the else statement but the first input is 34110 which is a multiple of 10 and 6 so it is printing both lines. How do I make it so if the first if statement is correct it ignores the second?

Comment: You should remove ; from every if statement. This is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are new to programming. Not big issue,You did mistake in using brackets'{}' and semi-colon';' which is common.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
           int number = read.nextInt();
           
           //your code goes here
            if(number % 10 == 0 || number % 9 == 0)
                System.out.println("You won $200");
            if(number % 4 == 0 || number % 6 == 0)
                System.out.println("You won $50");
             else 
                System.out.println("Try again");
        }
    }
```

This might not be the result you want. If that is the case then use **else if** instead of **second if** in your code.

Comment: Thanks so much. I also saw that the first if statement was supposed to be && instead of || so the program works now.

Comment: If I was helpful feel free to upVote the answer and keep learning.